# Rails 4.2: Unknown Attribute or Server Error in Log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, actionview

I have a form with a `select_tag` and `options_from_collection_for_select` that I can't seem to get to pass. In the view, when the upload id is set to `uploadzip_id` I get a 302 redirect and when it's set to `uploadzip_ids`, I get a `Unknown Attribute` error.

I'm a bit confused as I have my relationship set up along with the foreign key. I do have another model with checkboxes called `Uploadpdf` that works fine.

Here is the set up..

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :uploadzip
end

class Uploadzip < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :campaign
end
```

**db/schema.rb**

```
  create_table "campaigns", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false

  create_table "uploadzips", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "file_name"
    t.string   "file_type"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.integer  "size"
    t.integer  "pages"
    t.string   "file_ident"
    t.string   "md5"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "campaign_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "uploadzips", "campaigns"
```

**app/controllers/campaign_controller.rb**

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @campaigns = Campaign.all.order("created_at DESC")
      end

      def new
        @campaign = Campaign.new
      end

      def create
        @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)

        if @campaign.save
            flash[:success] = "Campaign Successfully Launched!"
            redirect_to @campaign
        else
            flash[:error] = "There was a problem launching your Campaign."
            redirect_to new_campaign_path
        end
      end

    .....

  private

      def campaign_params
        params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, :comment, :uploadzip_ids, uploadpdf_ids: [])
      end
end
```

**views/campaigns/_form.rb**

```
<%= form_for @campaign, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>

    .....some typical fields..

    <%= f.label :data_file, class: "right-label" %>

    <%= select_tag campaign[uploadzip_ids], 
                options_from_collection_for_select(
                Uploadzip.all, :id, :file_name
                ), { include_blank: "Include a Zip File" } %>

    .....some more typical fields

<% end %>
```

**Update**

I have changed the code to better reflect the foreign key as suggested. Creating a campaign is now successful but it's not associating with the chosen `uploadzip` Zip file selected. When calling `@campaign.uploadzip`, it returns `nil`.

Here is the updated code:

```
<%= select_tag "uploadzip[campaign_id]",
    options_from_collection_for_select(
    Uploadzip.all, :id, :file_name
    ), { include_blank: "Include a Zip File" } %>
```

I also changed the controller `params.require` to..

```
  def campaign_params
    params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, :comment, :campaign_id, uploadpdf_ids: [])
  end
```

Comment: Is the `Uploadzip` model supposed to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: @Daiku - It does in the source code. Not too sure how that was erased in my copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Member of a FaceBook group helped me figure it out by adding a little
extra logic in the controller..

```
  if @campaign.save

    zip = Uploadzip.find(params[:uploadzip_id])
    zip.campaign = @campaign
    zip.save

    flash[:success] = "Campaign Successfully Launched!"
    redirect_to @campaign
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was a problem launching your Campaign."
    redirect_to new_campaign_path
  end
```

..which was met with changing the select_tag's name.

```
  <%= select_tag :uploadzip_id,
      options_from_collection_for_select(
      Uploadzip.all, :id, :file_name
      ), { include_blank: "Include a Zip File" } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your association set-up,the **foreign_key** should be **`campaign_id`** not **`uploadzip_id`**. You should either change your **associations** or **foreign_key** according to your use-case.

And also I recommend you to follow these [**Guides**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to know more about associations.

Comment: Thank you Pavan. I'm still having a trouble nailing down the association. I updated the code above. Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

The 302 redirect may not be a bad thing, since you're doing a `redirect_to new_campaign_path`. Are the records created correctly when you use `uploadzip_id` in both the view and controller `params.permit` section?

Comment: The 302 is not terrible other than it's not saving the record. I've been trying a combination of things in the `params.permit` section but I'm not too sure what the "correct" way that syntax should look.