# Rails 4: Factory Girl & Rspec with associated Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I previously fixed an issue with some code that works though it is a little ugly. Problem now is that it breaks my tests! The idea here is that I can create a Campaign and associate 1 zip-file and one-to-many pdfs.

Previous question and solution:
[Rails 4.2: Unknown Attribute or Server Error in Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608753/rails-4-2-unknown-attribute-or-server-error-in-log)

Here is the failure message:

**console**

```
  1) CampaignsController POST #create with valid params 
     Failure/Error: post :create, campaign: attributes_for(:campaign)
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Uploadzip with 'id'=
     # ./app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:15:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/campaigns_controller_spec.rb:36:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

..and the rest of the code.

**spec/factories/campaigns.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :campaign do |x|
        x.sequence(:name) { |y| "Rockfest 201#{y} Orange County" }
        x.sequence(:comment) { |y| "Total attendance is #{y}" }
    end
end
```

**spec/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb**

```
  describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid params" do
      before(:each) do
        post :create, campaign: attributes_for(:campaign)
      end

      .........

      end
```

**app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb**

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController

......................

      def create
        @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)

        if @campaign.save

            zip = Uploadzip.find(params[:uploadzip_id])
            zip.campaign = @campaign
            zip.save

            flash[:success] = "Campaign Successfully Launched!"
            redirect_to @campaign
        else
            ................
        end
      end

.......................

  private

      def campaign_params
        params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, :comment, :campaign_id, uploadpdf_ids: [])
      end

end
```

This appears simple and I assume it is, yet I've tried quit a few things and can't seem to get it to pass. How would I support the new controller logic in this test? Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

With zetitic's advice, I created the following code in which successfully passes.

```
before(:each) do
  @uploadzip = create(:uploadzip)
  post :create, campaign: attributes_for(:campaign), uploadzip_id: @uploadzip
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `uploadedzip_id` to the posted params:

```
before(:each) do
  post :create, campaign: attributes_for(:campaign), uploadedzip_id: 123456
end
```

Comment: The row with that ID must of course exist in the test database. You may need to create an UploadedZip via a factory in a before block, and use its ID.

Comment: Did it! I'll post the answer at the bottom of my post and credit you. Thanks!